# Añadir array a otro array en javascipt

Tags: javascript, array, object

Tengo unos inputs de donde cojo los valores para rellenar las variables, como el ejemplo de aquí abajo.

```
var artR = 'Mando Xbox';
var prec = '250';
var artV = 'Xbox';

articulos = {}
```

Entonces al hacer click en un botón necesito que los valores de los campos se añadan al array mediante javascript y se vayan guardando todos en este array para posteriormente añadirlos a una tabla en la misma página y tenerlos guardados en la variable para procesarlos luego y guardarlos cuando lo desee el usuario.

Pero no puedo de ninguna manera hacer que en el array se vayan metiendo los valores en el índice...

Resultado deseado o parecido (array de arrays):

```
articulos = [
    {
        articuloR: 'Mando Xbox',
        precio:    '250',
        articuloV: 'Xbox'
    },
    {
        articuloR: 'Mando PS',
        precio:    '200',
        articuloV: 'Ps 4'
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes iniciar con:

```
var articulos = [];
```

Luego, cada vez que hagas click, deberias de insertar el objeto dentro del array, con el [metodo push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp):

```
articulos.push({articuloR: artR, precio: prec, articuloV: artV});
```

Comment: Haciendolo de esta manera, ya lo intenté y lo que hace es siempre sobreescribirme el índice 0...

Comment: No estas instanciando la variable articulos como un nuevo array cada vez que se hace la llamada al boton? Podrias colocar tu codigo en tu pregunta? =)

Comment: Sí, era eso, no me di cuenta de que lo había puesto dentro de la función del click

Comment: Jeje, suele pasar =)

Answer (score 1):

Porque no lo haces con un objeto y luego lo transformas en una cadena JSON

var obj = new Object();

obj.ARTICULOR = "Mando xbox" 
obj.PRECIO = 250 
obj.ARTICULOV = "Ps 4"

var sCadena = JSON.Stringify(obj);

y con eso obtienes la cadena.